# How to install Anaconda on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, anaconda

How to install [Anaconda for Python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) on Ubuntu?

Is there a way to use `apt-get install`?

I only have command line access to my server. How do I install Anaconda on Ubuntu 14.04 from the command line?

Comment: I'm sorry but I just have to ask does your system have the package `buns` installed? I've heard `Anaconda` only works with that installed.

Comment: it would be ideal if there was an answer entirely in the command line. Specially, it seems that the current answers do not tell us how to download the most recent installer for Anaconda. i.e. the `wget` seem short lived.

Comment: I think this works: you can install everything on terminal like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1412558/230288

Comment: Upvote this github issue: https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/anaconda-client/issues/695

Answer (score 64, accepted):

See [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/) Hompepage for more detail!

**Installation Instructions [Linux Install]**

These instructions explain how to install Anaconda on a Linux system.

After [downloading](http://continuum.io/downloads) the Anaconda installer, run the following command from a terminal:

```
$ bash Anaconda-2.x.x-Linux-x86[_64].sh
```

After accepting the license terms, you will be asked to specify the install location (which defaults to `~/anaconda`).

<sub>**Note**: You do NOT need root privileges to install Anaconda, if you select a user writable install location, such as `~/anaconda.*` After the self extraction is finished, you should add the anaconda binary directory to your PATH environment variable.</sub>

<sub>As all of Anaconda is contained in a single directory, uninstalling Anaconda is easy (you simply remove the entire install location directory).</sub>

---

If you encounter any issues, please try disabling your antivirus software.
Linux/OS X Uninstall

As all of Anaconda is contained in a single directory, uninstalling Anaconda is simple (you simply remove the entire install location directory):

```
$ rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

Comment: how would you recommend installing systemwide?

Comment: How long does the bash installation take, after the download?

Comment: @nealmcb on my SSD it took less than 10 minutes

Comment: how do you do the first step in the terminal **without a web browser**? I am trying to run this in a docker container so I need the command.

Comment: @Charlie Parker: I am sorry, but I don't have an answer to this questions.

Comment: So you don't know how to do the "After downloading the Anaconda installer" in the command line? (I am quoting your answer)

Comment: Be careful as Anaconda seems to install their own version of `moc` (for building Qt apps), which may conflict with the system libraries if you compile when `/home/USER/anaconda3/bin` is in your path.

Comment: @CharlieParker Check this guide, essentially you can just curl the file and save the response: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Is it better to install it as root or not?

Comment: you can install everything on therminal like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1412558/230288

Answer (score 87):

You can use `wget` to download from commandline:

For Python3, 64 bits version (most Ubuntu distros)

```
    wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

And after download is finished do:

```
    bash Anaconda3-2022.05-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

For users using Python2, the "3" directly after Anaconda should be changed to a 2.

Source: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/stable/user-guide/install/linux.html

Comment: how do i update anaconda?

Comment: $ conda update conda,
$ conda update anaconda.

Check http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html

Comment: from your wget commands, it seems that its not possible to install anaconda through apt-get or some more "official" ubuntu package manager? Is that right?

Comment: it seems that the current answer do not tell us how to download the most recent installer for Anaconda. i.e. the `wget` seem short lived. Do you know how to d that part?

Comment: @Vivek can you clarify what your conda update thing is?

Comment: This installs anaconda for python2, not python3. (Just a clarification to future readers).

Comment: You can see the list of versions available here: https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/.

Answer (score 63):

Nobody has explained here why `apt-get` and other package managers don't have packages for anaconda.

An important reason for this is that anaconda is meant to be usable by a user who, for whatever reason, doesn't have root privileges. In that case the user just installs into `~/anaconda`, changes her own `PATH` and `PYTHONHOME` variables so as to run `~/anaconda/python`, and is capable of controlling her personal python distribution, while modifying the "system" python might require an administrator's help.

Package managers always require sysadmin privileges.

Comment: Package managers don't always need root access; Maven, Gradle, cpan, and NPM do fine without. Even then you could put the package manager itself in the Ubuntu repository and have it install packages on a per-user or even per-project basis.

Comment: When requiere project that have a "pricing" don't use standarized package management it always yield a warning for me. Then I deploy it in a docker environnement... not that a big deal for an environnement manager.

Comment: you can install everything on therminal like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1412558/230288

Comment: I think for every user developing in a pc without root access there are 99 other users with root access. apt install conda would be so much easier than copying the wget command every single time

Comment: @polvoazul, I agree that just about all home users have root. However there are a lot of corporate users who don't

Comment: No problem, keep the user level installer. But why not add it to apt as well?

Answer (score 23):

If you are trying to it entirely in command line you use a bash script 
[python 2 anaconda install bash script](https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/4e48b0dc307a2d50f4b7701dbc54573d):

```
# Go to home directory
cd ~

# You can change what anaconda version you want at 
# https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda
rm Anaconda2-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 

# Reload default profile
source ~/.bashrc

conda update conda
```

[python 3 anaconda install bash script](https://gist.github.com/mGalarnyk/05e4147b7fdfe4f94863e693644b43d9)

```
# Go to home directory
cd ~

# You can change what anaconda version you want at 
# https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p ~/anaconda
rm Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc 

# Reload default profile
source ~/.bashrc

conda update conda
```

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-ubuntu-anaconda-65623042cb5a

Comment: This actually answers the question and should be the accepted answer

Comment: I think my answer is similarly good to yours you can install everything on therminal like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1412558/230288 I am curious how you skipped the activate conda step I did

Comment: They've also now documented this good method at: https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/#quick-command-line-install "Quick command line install"

Answer (score 12):

In addition to @Vivek's answer, to get the latest python3 64-bit Linux version:

```
CONTREPO=https://repo.continuum.io/archive/
# Stepwise filtering of the html at $CONTREPO
# Get the topmost line that matches our requirements, extract the file name.
ANACONDAURL=$(wget -q -O - $CONTREPO index.html | grep "Anaconda3-" | grep "Linux" | grep "86_64" | head -n 1 | cut -d \" -f 2)
wget -O ~/Downloads/anaconda.sh $CONTREPO$ANACONDAURL
bash ~/Downloads/anaconda.sh -b -p $HOME/anaconda3
```

The `grep` filters in line 3 can be altered to match your requirements, of course.

Q: *What is going on here?*

- `wget -q -O - URL` quietly (`-q`) gets the html at `URL` (in this case https://repo.continuum.io/archive/, which is accessed as `$CONTREPO`) and sends it to standard out (`-O -`).
- | is called "pipe", and sends the output of the preceding command to the next command.
- `grep "text"` returns the lines from its input that contain `text`. So first, we select all lines that contain "Anaconda3", then of those, we select all lines containing "Linux", and then all lines containing "86_64" (for the 64-bit version).
- `head -n 1` returns the first line of the input. I rely on the website maintaining order so that the most recent version is on top.
- `cut -d \" -f 2` splits the input on the double quote characters (`-d \"`), which surround the filename in the HTML's href, and returns the second field (`-f 2`), being the target of the href.
- `-b -p path` options make the installation non-interactive "[silent-mode](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/#linux-macos)", where you silently accept the license and are not asked for confirmation for the installation path.

Answer (score 5):

[Watch this video for complete installation](https://youtu.be/JP60kTsVJ8E)

[Download Anaconda from continuum here](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

To install Python 3.6 version

```
sudo bash Anaconda3-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

For Python 2.7 version

```
 sudo bash Anaconda2-4.3.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Run Navigator

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Run Spyder IDE

```
spyder
```

Run Jupyter Notebook

```
jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. `export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`
2. Then you can update them with:

   ```
   conda update conda
   conda update anaconda
   ```

Comment: i try to use 
export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pyenv to install Anaconda, and then easily switch back and forth between your system Python and your Anaconda Python:

1. [Install Pyenv](https://www.tecmint.com/pyenv-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-in-linux/)
2. `pyenv install anaconda3-5.3.0` (`pynev install -l` to see what versions of anaconda are available)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Anaconda repo archive page](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/) and select an appropriate version that you'd like to install.

After that, just do:

```
 # replace this `Anaconda3-version.num-Linux-x86_64.sh` with your choice
~$ wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-vers.num-Linux-x86_64.sh
~$ bash Anaconda3-version.num-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

---

**Concrete Example:**

As of this writing, ***Anaconda3-2019.03*** is the latest version. So,

```
$ wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

After installation is completed, you can also optionally delete the installation script by:

```
$ rm -rf Anaconda3-5.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Comment: you can install everything on therminal like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1412558/230288 which is similar to yours.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want a apt-based way of installing things.
Anaconda maintains an apt repo for conda which allows for installation of one version of conda for all the users on a system.

as of 2023, [anaconda has instructions on how to to this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/rpm-debian.html)

The short version: (note, requires root access)

Install our public gpg key to trusted store

```
curl https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/gpgkeys/anaconda.asc | gpg --dearmor > conda.gpg
install -o root -g root -m 644 conda.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Check whether fingerprint is correct (will output an error message otherwise)

```
gpg --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg --no-default-keyring --fingerprint 34161F5BF5EB1D4BFBBB8F0A8AEB4F8B29D82806
```

Add our Debian repo

As root do:
# echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/debrepo/conda stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conda.list

**NB:** If you receive a Permission denied error when trying to run the above command (because `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/conda.list` is write protected), try using the following command instead:

```
# echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/conda-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/debrepo/conda stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/conda.list
```

Then do the usual

```
$ sudo apt-get update 

$ sudo apt-get install conda
```

For each user, they will need to add /opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/condabin to their $PATH and do something like "conda init bash" to start using the system conda.

Alternatively, you can, as root,

```
# ln -s /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d
```

So that it is installed system wide.

There are additional instructions on setting up a system-wide /opt/conda/.condarc file at the anaconda site.

[2] https://www.anaconda.com/blog/rpm-and-debian-repositories-for-miniconda

Answer (score 0):

I think this is cleaner:

```
# install python
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wget

wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh
bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda

# source /Users/my_username/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
source ~/miniconda/bin/activate
# conda init zsh
conda init
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
conda install conda-build

conda create -n iit_synthesis python=3.9
conda activate iit_synthesis
#conda remove --name metalearning2 --all
```

inspired from:

- https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/linux.html
- mac provides the nice renaming and downloading to location: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/macos.html
- mac os (no brew): https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902863/1601580
- brew but not sure if recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72520702/1601580
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615322/zsh-conda-pip-installs-command-not-found/72521324#72521324