# How do I get Ubuntu to use Anaconda's python instead of the standard /usr/lib/python...?

Tags: python, environment-variables, .profile

I installed Anaconda using instructions provided on the main website, which are similar to those that can be seen here: [How to install Anaconda on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/installing-anaconda-python-on-ubuntu)

However, I found that I had to manually change PATH using an `export` command in ~/.profile (as per official Ubuntu instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) to get the system to know about ~/anaconda/bin:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
export PATH="~/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Already, this was surprising because Anaconda should have been able to sort things out correctly itself during installation.

Now, another issue I am having is that when I run `python` in terminal, it defaults to using the Python in /usr/lib/python..., rather than ~/anaconda/bin/python.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you login again after changing the profile?

Comment: @muru Yes. That was an instruction in the official instructions too. I'd like to note that commands like `conda` (which are in ~/anaconda/bin) work just fine in the terminal, so the `export` commands are fine. The issue is that /usr/lib/python command is overriding ~/anaconda/bin/python, and I don't know why.

Comment: did you check your bashrc isn't overriding your profile?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh How could I make sure that that isn't happening?

Comment: The issue may be that the tilde character doesn't get expanded when inside quotes (even double quotes) - have you tried replacing `~` by `$HOME`?

Comment: @steeldriver That fixed the issue! Can you write up something about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tilde (`~`) character is not expanded when enclosed in quotes (even double quotes, which allow most other filename expansions). You should replace `~` by `$HOME` in the PATH export:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. Tried this and it works for me

> > > source bin/activate ~/anaconda3/