# How do I get Ubuntu to use Anaconda's python instead of previous Python installation?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtualenv, anaconda

I know that a very similar question has been asked [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599414/how-do-i-get-ubuntu-to-use-anacondas-python-instead-of-the-standard-usr-lib-py), but I think my issue is different.

I have just installed Anaconda2 following the Anaconda documentation steps (downloading and executing the sh script), then re launching the shell.
I had a previously installed python version on /usr/bin, which was version 3.4.3. I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS.

I have created an environment which should run on python 2.7

```
conda create --name myenvpy2 python=2
source activate myenvpy2
```

If I look at my path, I have the following

```
echo $PATH
/home/gvo/anaconda2/envs/myenvpy2/bin:/home/gvo/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:...
```

On /home/gvo/anaconda2/envs/myenvpy2/bin I have the correct version of python

```
ls -l
python -> python2.7
```

And

```
./python --version
Python 2.7.12 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Therefore, when running simply python I would expect the same result, since this folder contains a python and is the first of the $PATH variable. However :

```
python --version
Python 3.4.3
```

This effectively seems to be the /usr/bin version of Python

```
>>> import sys
>>> print (sys.executable)
/usr/bin/python3
```

I don't understand why, despite a python can be found in the first folder of the path, it goes through another version of Python, found in a later folder.

Please note that with a python=3 environment created and sourced, it indeed uses the correct python version installed by anaconda, which adds a lot to my confusion.

```
python --version
Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Do you have any clue?

Comment: Can you do `ls -l /usr/bin/python{,2,3}`? I am curious what they are symlinked to.

Comment: >lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 mars  20  2015 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
>lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 mars  20  2015 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7 >lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 mars  20  2015 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.4

Comment: Do you have an alias defined for `python`? what does `type python` say?

Comment: I have : python is aliased to `python3'. That would explain why it goes looking for a python3 somewhere else!

Comment: Once the alias removed it works, thanks for the help, I didn't knew about aliases. If you want to add it as answer I will accept it.

Comment: Sidenote : you can use `which` command to find which command is aliased or linked to which file. for instance `which python2` returns `/usr/local/bin/python2` on my system.