# Python to Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7

I am completely new to python. I have Python 2.7.9 on my computer. Now I need to install anaconda and do scientific programming. How can I proceed to have anaconda and use it to code some problems?

Comment: Why you'd want to use Anaconda instead of an Ubuntu default Python distribution?

Comment: I have heard that Anaconda is pretty useful to do scientific programming. That's why. Is the default Python distribution can be used to do scientific programming instead of Anaconda? Please illuminate me!

Comment: That's heavily depends on how you plan to use it: if you just want to write some code for your scientific tasks - than default Python (with plenty of package already available in the repository) is more than enough; from my experience it's also more than enough for clusters, the only thing when Anaconda is better - if you somehow want to create a cluster from a number of various PCs (with multiple Python versions), than using Anaconda makes it less painful to have same Python environment (or Windows, it's my main Python environment under Windows).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Anaconda python on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/installing-anaconda-python-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a duplicate, maybe best is just install Spyder. It has the usual things that a novice and expert scientific python programmer will need. Exploring variables, autocomplete commands and good help files. It is in the default repos.