# Environmental variables for Anaconda

Tags: python, environment-variables

I'm new to UNIX.  On my Windows work computer I have Anaconda and do a lot of Python work.  I installed Anaconda on Ubuntu 14.  I would like to type `conda` or `activate` in a terminal and have those work.

On Windows, the path is modified to include `anaconda/scripts`.  Should I modify the path to include `$home/anaconda/scripts`?  If so where and how?

Alternatively should I define a variable like `$conda` which would be that path above so in a terminal I could type `$conda/conda`?  If so where and how?

My home is encrypted.  The answer could affect all users or just me, I'm the only user anyways.  Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about Anaconda. For ways to modify `PATH` you may want to study the tutorial [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables).

Comment: Possible duplicate of 'http://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/installing-anaconda-python-on-ubuntu'

Answer (score 1):

From the [Anaconda user guide](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/launcher):

> For example, using the environment named “research”, a user could enter the following command to update the system PATH.:
>
> export PATH=/opt/anaconda/envs/research/bin:$PATH

You can add the export to the end of `/home/user/.bashrc` for a persistent solution.

Also see the [Environment Variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) link from @Gunnar Hjalmarsson for more info.