# Subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Tags: 16.04, python, anaconda

Long time lurker. Don't know if this is a duplicate but I havent found any answers to my problem yet.

Every time I try to update or install anything I'm getting the following error.

This started after I installed anaconda. Don't know if it's connected but feels like it.

```
E: python-decorator: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-simplegeneric: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: ipython: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: python-urllib3: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-chardet: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-requests: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: python-boto: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: python-bs4: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-django: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-html5lib: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-pil: 6.7416:subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-imaging: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: python-libxml2: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-lxml: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-mysqldb: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-ndg-httpsclient: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-pip: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-pygments: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-queuelib: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-cssselect: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-w3lib: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-scrapy: dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
E: python-setuptools: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-sqlparse: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-wheel: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: python-tz: subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the version of Python on your system? That's usually what 'dependency problems' indicate.

Comment: I changed it to point to anaconda. There is python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6(the anaconda one). I'm very much a noob with linux and I'm still trying to learn. Sorry if it's a dumb problem.

Comment: Change it back. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu

Comment: But I need to use anaconda for this class in university...

Comment: So? Undo whatever haywire method you did to fix your system, then use the linked instructions to install anaconda properly.