# New to Linux - Installing and Using a Text Editor for Using Python and PyTorch

Tags: python, text-editor

I'm new to using Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) and I've installed Vim to use as a text editor, in order to use python and pytorch.

However, I haven't been able to open anything resembling a text editor. I've opened Vim in the terminal but not in an way in which I can save or edit files. I'm familiar with Komodo for Windows 10 so I feel I would know it if I see it.

I haven't been able to find any online guide or instructions on how to actually go about using Vim, but I'm certainly open to using other editors.

In particular I need to make use of .ipynb and .py files.

Any advice on how to begin would be amazing, or being pointed to any available resources or guides!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.linfo.org/vi/index.html /That's the link of a good vi tutorial. Besides, you can use gedit as @Rinzwind said. Just open your terminal and type gedit.

Comment: komodo is available for Linux 64 bits; download it, unpack it, don't forget to add permission at executable main file with `chmod +x komodo.sh` and run it with `./komodo.sh` to install it (`komodo.sh` is the name of the executable main file)

Comment: Atom is good as general GUI editor for any programming language.  Vim has steep learning curve, but once you get the basic down, it flows. If you insist on command line one, use `nano` - it's simple enough

Answer (score 1):

1. A very simple to use editor is [gedit](https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/)
2. If you want to use an IDE for python, you can use `pycharm`.

   A link which describes [How to install pycharm](https://itsfoss.com/install-pycharm-ubuntu/)
   Note: If you'd like to use it - I'd suggest using the `umake` install method
3. If you need to use `.ipynb` (ipython notebook) - you might focus on [The Jupyter Notebook](https://ipython.org/notebook.html)

   [**jupyter install**](https://jupyter.org/install)

   **Installing Jupyter using Anaconda**

   We strongly recommend installing Python and Jupyter using the Anaconda Distribution, which includes Python, the Jupyter Notebook, and other commonly used packages for scientific computing and data science.

   [See this Q&A regarding how to install Anaconda](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu)

   After you installed Anaconda, run the following command from the command line:

   jupyter notebook

Note: `vi` isn't editor for beginners (some references):

- ([Stack Overflow: Helping One Million Developers Exit Vim](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/))
- A (fake) book focus on *Exiting Vim*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[gedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit) is the native text editor and it has tools dedicated to python, like [python console](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-pyconsole.html.en)

Or if you want  a python specific editor try "anaconda". It is in the ubuntu software center :)

Answer (score 0):

Vim is a very powerful text editor having lots of features in it.
To can get a basic understanding of vim you can use **vimtutor**.

To run vimtutor open your terminal and type the command

> **vimtutor**

You can also customize your vim editor as per your needs using a .vimrc file. You can use the below link to get a deep knowledge about vim.

http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/