# Silent Anaconda installation

Tags: software-installation, docker, anaconda

I need to install Anaconda to the Docker container with Ubuntu. But after I copy and execute the installer it asks to agree with the license agreement. Is there any way to make a silent installation?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the official documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/silent-mode/):

Download the installer as `miniconda.sh`.

Run `miniconda.sh -b -p ~/path/to/install/to`

> The installer will not prompt you for anything, including setup of your shell to activate conda.

`-b` is for batch mode, which the docs say assumes you agree to the license(s), and also won't modify `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

`-p {path}` is to define the installation path.

`-f` can be used to force the installation if the installation path already exists.

The linked documentation has more, including how to activate this type of conda installation for the current shell.