# I tried to install stable diffusion in my Ubuntu 20.04,but i am stuck on after creating git hub clone

Tags: kubuntu, repository

I am  installing stable diffusion, in my Ubuntu , but after i cloned using this command:

```
git clone https://github.com/lstein/stable-diffusion.git
```

then used this command:

```
cd stable-diffusion
```

then i used this command:

```
mkdir -p models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/
```

after this one i tried this command :

```
mv ~/Downloads/sd-v1-4.ckpt models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/model.ckpt
```

but after inputting this command : i am seeing no such file or directory, then i went to this command:

```
conda env create -f environment.yaml
```

but i am seeing :

```
conda: command not found
```

is there anyway find solution for this problem

Comment: Edit your question, and remove the tab character from before `I tried to install`. Make it start on the left edge. You can enhance formatting further with these tips: https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Anaconda on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505919/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install conda try this:

```
sudo apt install conda
```